# shine out of/from/in

Tags: prepositions, difference

> Corinthians 4:6:  " For God, who said, "Let light **shine out of**
>   darkness," made his light shine in our hearts to give us the light of
>   the knowledge of God's glory displayed in the face of Christ."

Why is "out of" better than "from" and "in" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure “out of” is necessarily better than “from” - these two terms seem to me to be more or less interchangeable in this context. Maybe “out of”, since it contains the word “out”, more dramatically evokes an image of the light escaping the darkness. “In” has a slightly different meaning here- if the light shines *in* the darkness there is light to be found somewhere *in* the middle of the darkness. But light shining *from* or *out of* the darkness maybe suggests that there is a sharper contrast between light and dark, in other words, that the light is more prominent. This is a very subtle distinction, though- really, I think any of those terms would work. I’d be curious to know what the original Greek (?) uses.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation.  I don't know Greek either, so unable to offer you more information.